# How to get input values when opened by material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to get the values from input where it opened by Material Dialog box. I tried below but the values is not changed one.

Please see this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/tiiMwvQTB4sbz5uTAByP?p=preview

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
      const dialogResultExampleDialog = new DialogResultExampleDialog()
      console.log(dialogResultExampleDialog.hero) <--- this value is not the changed value 
    });
  }
}

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: String
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Hello"
  }
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

Comment: `dialogResultExampleDialog.hero` value is the value initialized by `DialogResultExampleDialog`, what do You expect ? `result` is the value returned from dialog modal instance.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. yes the result values is `md-dialog-close="Option 1"` but I need to find a way to get the form values once it submitted. So I tried above I created Hero object and pass that into dialogResultExampleDialog and tried to change with ngModel but end result is not the changed one...

Comment: plunker provided throws errors at runtime 
`ERROR Error: The selector "dialog-result-example-dialog" did not match any elements`

Comment: I created that plunker based on this material example link https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples may be it's broken already ?

Comment: I answered with possible solution.

Comment: @RobC https://plnkr.co/edit/gauoNhO0Un8evNqhCtYs?p=preview

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

If You want to return value from dialog instance You should call dialog instance close method in Your dialog component class.

To do that, I added `close` method to `DialogResultExampleDialog` class. This method simply calls `this.dialogRef.close(this.hero);`

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jz2uln0mjMt3v6lp9fnU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know